# rubyzip coaching

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

```
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(folderpath) do |z|
        z.print IO.read(folderpath)
```

In the code above, I have `Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(file_path) do |z|`. I do not understand, what the do `|z|` mean? What does |z| refer to? Can I for example change |z| to other, example is |changez| ?

I got the complete code here 
http://blog.devinterface.com/2010/02/create-zip-files-on-the-fly/ but I can not undestand the 1st line of do |z| .

Comment: You might want to have a look at this article: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/. I'll change your tags, since this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever comes inside `||`, considered to be the parameters for the anonymous method (or lambda expression) that comes next,

for ex:

```
  (1..3).each do |n|
       puts n
  end
```

can be rewritten as

```
  (1..3).each {|n| puts n}
```

|n| could be anything, just a name for a variable.